# ufw can't open 23 port on centos

Tags: centos, telnet, ufw

I deployed a telnet on my centos7 in VMWare and I tried the ufw to open the 23 port,

```
$ sudo ufw allow 23/tcp
$ sudo ufw enable
```

then I tried to connect it use telnet from windows10 outside,

```
$ telnet my-centos-ip 23
```

but it failed, displayed "Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed"

then I used the firewall-cmd to open the 23 port

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-ports=23/tcp
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

and it works when I connect it from windows using

```
$ telnet my-centos-ip 23
```

I'm wondering why it happened like this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

ufw and firewalld can't work together, so after I stop the firewalld the ufw can work correctly